# how to use selected option of form select element in zend framework2?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormSelect and I did not find the way to set selected value in select element.

```
$countryList = array_merge (array('empty_option' => 'Please choose...'),     
$this->common()->getCountryList() );
$country->setValueOptions($countryList);
$country->setValue(array('AT' => 'AUSTRIA'));
echo $this->formSelect($country);
```

Comment: Should be just `$country->setValue('AT');`

Comment: take a look @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588272/zend-framework-set-selected-value-in-select-box-dropdown-list

Answer (score 1):

```
$country->setValue('AT');
As above, you can use setValue() for making 'AT' as selected.
```