# Set selected value in form of zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I created a form in zend framework. Here I want to set selected value from option while editing record. For example record have group id value 3.
This works fine in while adding record and while editing record i am not getting selected to third option.
I wrote below code but its not working.

```
   $group_id = $this->createElement('select','group_id');
   $group_id->setLabel('Category:')
               ->addMultiOptions(array(
                '1' => 'A',
                '2' => 'B', 
                '3' => 'C',
                '4' => 'D'                       
                    ))               
           ->setRequired(true)
           ->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper','Errors'));
   $group_id->setValue(3);
```

adminController.php

```
$id =  $this->_request->getParams('id');        
$row = $content->find($id)->toArray();
$form->populate($row[0]);
```

this populates data in all the fields only not setting selected for drop down.
Here 3rd option should show selected but always 1st option is showing selected.

Please let me know if i am missing anything here.

Comment: Your key is `string(3)` & you passing `int(3)` in setValue, try giving it like `$group_id->setValue('3');`

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and it works as it should, so problem has to be in different place.

Comment: Please check this link for your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588272/zend-framework-set-selected-value-in-select-box-dropdown-list

Comment: your code is working fine for me!

Comment: sorry its working fine, I was checking when I tried to edit detail.In case of $form->populate($abc[0]); I think It should show selected when we we are editing any record too.

Comment: Question is updated accordingly.

Comment: then show the code for that

Comment: Added controller code

Comment: is the field's name also group_id in database ? make sure they are same

Answer (score 1):

try without setting any selected value

```
$group_id = $this->createElement('select','group_id');
$group_id->setLabel('Category:')
           ->addMultiOptions(array(
            '1' => 'A',
            '2' => 'B', 
            '3' => 'C',
            '4' => 'D'                       
                ))               
       ->setRequired(true)
       ->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper','Errors'));
```

you can also do like below

```
$form->addElement('select','group_id',
array(
        'label'        => 'Category:',
        'multiOptions' => array(
            '1'  => 'A',
            '2'  => 'B',
            '3'  => 'C',
            '4'  => 'D',
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: I tried but its not showing selected to third option. Hoe to troubleshoot here?

Comment: try this without `setting any value`, it will work by default with populate a row array to the form

Comment: I have been tested it doesn't select selected option.

Comment: but it is working in my case and used version(1.11.10). which version you are using?